# How to grab the value from JSON object in Postgresql and insert into some other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.5

```html
{
  "orderId": "s",
  "fulfillerId": "qaqj8fkbmb",
  "orderDetailsUrl": "asd",
  "items": [
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Tetesting",
      "itemId": "item_1",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_1.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "1223",
      "productName": "Tesing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_1"
    },
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "itemId": "item_2",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_2.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "123",
      "productName": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

implement

-> grab value of orderId/fulfillerId/orderDetailsUrl and perform iteration for item array object to grab required values as its array of similar objects

-> Store in a variable

-> then perform the insert operation

Somehow its not working

**Desired Output:**

**Item Table**

- itemId
- fullfillerId
- orderId
- skuCode

++ all remaining data from JSON in Item Table

**ItemDetails Table**

- itemId
- orderDetailsUrl
- taskId
- quantity

I have tried various jsonb formatting but exact output is not achieved after parsing, I am not able to pick values from JSON and use Insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plpgsql block for illustration how you may do it. `raise notice` would be replaced with the relevant command(s), `insert` for example.

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare 
j constant json default $json$
{
  "orderId": "s",
  "fulfillerId": "qaqj8fkbmb",
  "orderDetailsUrl": "asd",
  "items": [
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Tetesting",
      "itemId": "item_1",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_1.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "1223",
      "productName": "Tesing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_1"
    },
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "itemId": "item_2",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_2.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "123",
      "productName": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_2"
    }
  ]
}
$json$;
r record;
begin
    -- Item
    for r in select j->>'fulfillerId' fullfillerid, j->>'orderId' orderid, t->>'itemId' itemid, t->>'skuCode' skucode
     from json_array_elements(j -> 'items') t loop
        raise notice '% % % %', r.fullfillerid, r.orderid, r.itemid, r.skucode;
    end loop;
    --ItemDetails
    for r in select j->>'orderDetailsUrl' orderdetailsurl, t->>'itemId' itemid, t->>'taskId' taskid, (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity
     from json_array_elements(j -> 'items') t loop
        raise notice '% % % %', r.orderdetailsurl, r.itemid, r.taskid, r.quantity;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

An insert will be simpler, w/o a loop:

```sql
insert into target_table ( list - of - columns ) 
  select 
    j->>'orderDetailsUrl' orderdetailsurl, 
    t->>'itemId' itemid, 
    t->>'taskId' taskid, 
    (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity
    -- other expressions maybe
  from json_array_elements(j -> 'items') t;
```

As a function that inserts into `item` table and `itemietails` table:

```sql
create or replace function json_items(raw_data json)
returns void language plpgsql as
$$
begin
 insert into itemdetails(itemid, orderdetailsurl, taskid, quantity) 
  select 
    t->>'itemId', 
    raw_data->>'orderDetailsUrl', 
    t->>'taskId', 
    (t->>'quantity')::numeric
  from json_array_elements(raw_data  -> 'items') t;

 insert into item(itemid, fullfillerid, orderid, skucode, dte, itemdescription)
  select 
    t->>'itemId', 
    raw_data->>'fullfillerId', 
    raw_data->>'orderId', 
    t->>'skuCode',
    t->>'dte',
    t->>'itemDescription'
  from json_array_elements(raw_data  -> 'items') t;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: will there be only 2 rows after completion of this function? Stefanov.sm @Stefanov.sm

Comment: There will be as many rows as the number of items in the `"items"` array in the JSON. I assume that the JSON would be an argument of the function and not a constant as it is in the illustration block.

Comment: so i have to update insert in place of raise notice?? so if that's the case there will be 4 insert queries for 2 items in the json ?  @Stefanov.sm

Comment: 2 target tables are item table and item details table, if you could help how to perform insert statement with proper positioning in function call with json as a param it would be helpful @Stefanov.sm  @@Stefanov.sm

Comment: @AagamDoshi I have added a function definition in my answer. You may need to add fields and expressions in `item` insert statement.